# Animated Loading GIF

Tags: transparency, photoshop, gif, animated-gif

So, my background is in the color `#DBDBDB`. I need an animated loading image like [this one](http://images.apple.com/global/elements/quicktime/loading.gif) for my site's background. Unfortunately since GIFs don't support partial transparency, I'm left with a white outline in my background. I've tried to take this image and edit it to use the same background color to no avail. Then I tried to make a loading animation of my own but that came out horrible. So I do not know what to do. Can anyone help me? I would like to use [this image](http://images.apple.com/global/elements/quicktime/loading.gif) but instead of a white outline, I would like an outline in the color `#DBDBDB` or a background `#DBDBDB`

Or to be told how to do this in CS5.5

Comment: Off topic. Not a programming question. Graphics Design @ Stack Exchange can help you : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Yes, I knew that it was off topic, I'm a bit new to StackOverflow so I didn't know there was a Graphics Design site, but I know this is where to go for quick intuitive answers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the wonderful little service [AjaxLoad](http://ajaxload.info/) to generate a loading animation for any combination of colors. Just pick `#DBDBDB` as the background color and use "Indicator Big" as your style.

Here's your image:
[image: loading image]

Comment: That's why I love StackOverflow...

Comment: NOOOO just a couple of seconds faster than me.  Good job :)