# transparent animated gifs without white border

Tags: gif

For my jQuery web app I search for a nice animated loading gif.
I have searched for hours ...
I found:
preloaders.net, LoadInfo.net, ajaxload.info, LoadingAPNG.com, Chimply.com and more.

But they ALL have this very ugly white border when transparent.
If you don't know what I mean, please see:
http://www.graphicmania.net/creating-gif-images-without-white-borders-problem-in-photoshop-2/

I also found this stackoverflow question
[Animated Loading GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675744/animated-loading-gif)

But this guy has ONE background color.

The menu bar, which is my background (jquery ui dialog header bar), is NOT one color, so it has to be transparent.

Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using spin.js. it will not give that white background effect. moreover, it loads faster than gif file and easily configurable.

http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/

Comment: I looked at the url, browser support is good, seems to be a very good alternative!